# Ember access variable inside Mixin

Tags: javascript, ember.js, mixins

```
import Ember from 'ember';
import myConst from '../utils/constants';

export default Ember.Mixin.create(myConst, {
  getFieldId: function(productCode) {
        console.log(myConst.MY_METHODS.FIELD_ID); //Not able to access this
  }
});
```

My constants.js looks like

```
var myConst = {};

myConst.MY_METHODS = {
        FIELD_ID: "fieldId"
};

export default myConst;
```

I am unable to access myConst inside the mixin. What am I doing wrong ?

Comment: Why are you both mixin `myConst` in and accessing it directly?

Comment: I am new to Ember. COuld you explain what is the correct way to access myConst.MY_METHODS inside my mixin ?

Answer (score 2):

I think you're confusing a couple of concepts here. In your example, `myConst` is a utility module that contains some default values, right? In that case, you don't want to mix it in to your mixin (which is what you're doing with `Ember.Mixin.create(myConst, {...})`. You should be doing something like this:

```
import Ember from 'ember';
import myConst from '<app-name>/utils/constants';

export default Ember.Mixin.create({
  getFieldId: function(productCode) {
    console.log(myConst.MY_METHODS.FIELD_ID);
  }
});
```

If that doesn't work, it's likely something to do with your `import` path. I would start debugging by just `console.log`ing `myConst` to make sure you have the intended object from your module.

Comment: I suggest using the full path instead, something like `'<app-name>/utils/constants'`.

Comment: Well..I did already try the way you have (i.e. without passing myConst to create)...also verified the path for utils/constants.js...still is not working (not able to find myConst)

Comment: Just an FYI...when I debug...where the code (myConst.MY_METHODS) is converted/shown as _myAppUtilsConstants['default'].MY_METHODS

and I get the values for this converted code (adding watch)

Comment: Hmm sounds like something weird going on with your resolver than. Are you using Ember cli? What version?